Two boys trick another boy by prentending to be a girl online
I'm looking for an movie where two boys creates an fake Facebook account and start chatting with boy on their school. Later in the movie they start to send nudes and all his nudes ends up at school which leads to him committing suicide

Sounds like Disconnect from 2012 with Jason Bateman. From an online recap:

15-year-old outcast son (Jonah Bobo) is duped online by a couple of sadistic classmates. The two creeps develop a fake Facebook profile of a girl, strike up a friendship with the boy, and then ask that he send over a nude photo of himself, which they circulate throughout the school. When Kyle catches wind of what’s happened, he hangs himself

Here's the trailer.
